# Download a file from a website using windows task scheduler

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I was wondering if it would be possible to use the windows task scheduler to do the following:
 - Access a website
 - Key in login details, press enter
 - Navigate to the file type to download

I understand that mouse movements cant be tracked using the scheduler.
As such, I thought of using the "Tab" button to skip to the correct download file.

Any advice is much appreciated, thanks.

Regards
Peteson

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There are a number of scriptable solutions. A widely used Python solution is called Selenium. It can be used to write a set of steps to load the webpage in question -> enter the login details -> "submit" the form -> scrape the URL for the download -> download the file using the likes of `wget` or `curl` -> finish/cleanup session. There are other solutions, too.